# Are there open data for long-term potentiation/depression experiments?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, neurophysiology, computational-modeling

The following is Figure 8.2 from [Dayan & Abbott (2001)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262041997/theoretical-neuroscience/), p. 292:

[image: Dayan & Abbott (2001), Fig. 8.2]

It describes the phenomenon of long-term potentiation/depression (LTP/LTD): Change in synaptic strength (y-axis) is inversely proportional to pre/post-synaptic spike time difference (x-axis). The closer pre- and post-synaptic spike are together, the higher the change in synaptic strength. Does anybody know whether there exist openly available data for such experiments?

Comment: There are thousands of LTP papers; I'm sure some have open data, but they're all going to be quite different because they all have different research questions.

Comment: @BryanKrause: Sure! Can you point me to one of those papers or a repository that has such data?

Comment: I think it's really something you should put some effort into yourself if you want the data.